# Password generator returning 'Undefined" in textbox

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple password generator based on user input. I have all of the prompts and confirmations showing up and working but the end result is 'Undefined'.

```
> var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
> var specialChar = ["!@#$%^&*()-=_+"];
> var lowerCase = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'];
> var upperCase = ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'];
> var numbers = ['1234567890'];
> var passwordLen;
> var upperCase;
> var lowerCase;
> 
>  function checkpassLen() {
> var passwordLen = parseInt(prompt('How long should we make password? (8-128 characters'));
> confirm('You have selected ' + passwordLen + ' characters.');
> if (passwordLen > 128){
> alert('Too many characters selected. Please select a number between 8 and 128.');
> checkpassLen();
> 
> else if(passwordLen < 8){
> alert('Too few characters selected. Please select a number betweeen 8 and 128.');
> checkpassLen();
>   }
> else if (isNaN(passwordLen)){
> alert('Please enter a numerical value between 8 and 128.')
> checkpassLen();
>   }
> else{
> 
>   }
> return passwordLen
> }
>  
> 
>  function CheckspecChar(){
> specialChar = prompt('Would you like to include special characters? Type y or n.');
> confirm("You have selected " + specialChar + " for special characters.");
> if (specialChar === 'y') {
> console.log('Special characters selected.');
>     }
> else if (specialChar === 'n') { 
> console.log('No special characters included.');
>     }
> else {
> alert('Please enter y or n to choose.');
> specChar()
>     }
> return specialChar
>   }
> function checknumber(){
> numbers = prompt('Would you like to include numbers? Type y or n.');
> confirm("You have selected " + numbers + " for numbers.");
> if(numbers === 'y'){
> console.log('Numbers selected.');
>     }
> else if (numbers === 'n'){
> console.log('No numbers selected.');
> 
> else {
> alert('Please enter y or n to choose.');
> checknumber()
> 
>   }
> return numbers
> }
>  function checkCaselow(){
> lowerCase = prompt('Do you want to include lower case letters? Type y or n.');
> confirm("You have selected " + lowerCase + " lower case letters.");
> if(lowerCase === 'y'){
> console.log('Lower case letters selected.');
>     }
> else if ( lowerCase === 'n'){
> console.log('Lower case letters not selected.');
>   }
> else {
> alert('Please enter y or n to choose.');
> checkCaselow()
> 
>   }
> return lowerCase
> }
> function checkCaseupper(){
> upperCase = prompt('Do you want to include upper case letters? Type y or n');
> confirm("You have selected " + upperCase + " lower case letters.");
> if(upperCase === 'y'){
> console.log('Upper case letters selected.');
>     }
> else if ( upperCase === 'n'){
> console.log('Upper case letters not selected.');
>   }
> else {
> alert('Please enter y or n to choose.');
> checkCaseupper()
>   }
> return upperCase
> }
> Write password to the #password input
> function writePassword() {
> var password = generatePassword();
> var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
> 
> passwordText.value = password;
> 
> }
> function generatePassword() {
> var choiceIndex= [checkpassLen(), CheckspecChar(), checkCaseupper(), checkCaselow(), checknumber()];
> var passcheck =" ";
> for(var i = 0; i < passwordLen; i++) {
> var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choiceIndex.length);  
> password = password + choiceIndex[randomIndex];
> return password;
> 
> }
> 
> Add event listener to generate button
> generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);`
```

I tried changing the values for variable choiceIndex to the variable names instead of the functions and it made no difference. I am trying to have the inputs of the user stored and used to generate a random password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code.
You made some mistakes.
If you have any questions about the code just add a comment.

```
let generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
let specialChar = "!@#$%^&*()-=_+";
let lowerCase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
let upperCase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
let numbers = '1234567890';

function CheckPassLen() {
    let passwordLen = parseInt(prompt('How long should we make password? (8-128 characters'));
    confirm('You have selected ' + passwordLen + ' characters.');
    if (passwordLen > 128) {
        alert('Too many characters selected. Please select a number between 8 and 128.');
        CheckPassLen();
    } else if (passwordLen < 8) {
        alert('Too few characters selected. Please select a number betweeen 8 and 128.');
        CheckPassLen();
    } else if (isNaN(passwordLen)) {
        alert('Please enter a numerical value between 8 and 128.')
        CheckPassLen();
    }
    return passwordLen;
}


function CheckSpecChar() {
    let specialChar = prompt('Would you like to include special characters? Type y or n.');
    confirm("You have selected " + specialChar + " for special characters.");
    if (specialChar === 'y') {
        console.log('Special characters selected.');
    } else if (specialChar === 'n') {
        console.log('No special characters included.');
    } else {
        alert('Please enter y or n to choose.');
        CheckSpecChar();
    }
    return specialChar;
}

function CheckNumber() {
    let numbers = prompt('Would you like to include numbers? Type y or n.');
    confirm("You have selected " + numbers + " for numbers.");
    if (numbers === 'y') {
        console.log('Numbers selected.');
    } else if (numbers === 'n') {
        console.log('No numbers selected.');
    } else {
        alert('Please enter y or n to choose.');
        CheckNumber();
    }
    return numbers;
}

function CheckCaseLow() {
    let lowerCase = prompt('Do you want to include lower case letters? Type y or n.');
    confirm("You have selected " + lowerCase + " lower case letters.");
    if (lowerCase === 'y') {
        console.log('Lower case letters selected.');
    } else if (lowerCase === 'n') {
        console.log('Lower case letters not selected.');
    } else {
        alert('Please enter y or n to choose.');
        CheckCaseLow();
    }
    return lowerCase;
}

function CheckCaseUpper() {
    let upperCase = prompt('Do you want to include upper case letters? Type y or n');
    confirm("You have selected " + upperCase + " lower case letters.");
    if (upperCase === 'y') {
        console.log('Upper case letters selected.');
    } else if (upperCase === 'n') {
        console.log('Upper case letters not selected.');
    } else {
        alert('Please enter y or n to choose.');
        CheckCaseUpper();
    }
    return upperCase;
}

// Write password to the #password input
function WritePassword() {
    let password = GeneratePassword();
    let passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

    passwordText.value = password;
}

function GeneratePassword() {
    let choiceIndex = [CheckPassLen(), CheckSpecChar(), CheckCaseUpper(), CheckCaseLow(), CheckNumber()];
    let characters = "";
    let password = "";
    if (choiceIndex[1] === 'y') {
        characters = characters + specialChar;
    }
    if (choiceIndex[2] === 'y') {
        characters = characters + upperCase;
    }
    if (choiceIndex[3] === 'y') {
        characters = characters + lowerCase;
    }
    if (choiceIndex[4] === 'y') {
        characters = characters + numbers;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < choiceIndex[0]; i++) {
        let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
        password = password + characters[randomIndex];
    }
    return password;
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", WritePassword);
```